# Angular-js with typescript - should data be stored in controllers or services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-ng-repeat

I develop a web api server and recently started devloping the client side also, which is developed in Angular-js and typescript.

I have something I'm not sure about regarding the design of my client side code.

Say for example that I have a view that presents list of items and this view's controller is created many times, everytime a button is clicked (for example). This view presents a list of items and therefore this array is receieved throguh Http GET in the controller each time it is created, and the view has

```
 ng-repeat="item in vm.items"
```

However, it seems to me that if I save this list on a service, which from my understanding is created once per client only, I could use a single GET request once when the service is created and use it in the view like this:

```
ng-repeat="item in vm.service.items"
```

And updates to this list of items will happen through usage of signalr only.

Does the second approach has it's flaws? Because right now I can't see a reason for not doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sounds like a classic DAL-service for me. I would recommend you to work with a promise there so you are able to track when the desired data is resolved. Here is an example:

```
 export class EntityProvider {
        static serviceName: string = "entityProvider";

        private entity = null;

        static $inject : string[] = ["YourService", "$q"];
        constructor(yourService: YourService, private mQService: ng.IQService) {

        }

        get getEntity(): ng.IPromise<ConnectionInfoDto[]> {
            if (this.entity === null) {
                return this.yourService.getEntity()
                    .then(result => {
                        this.entity = result.data;
                        return this.entity;
                    });    
            } else {
                return this.mQService.when(this.entity);
            }
        }


        static bootstrap(aModule: ng.IModule) {
            return aModule.service(this.serviceName, EntityProvider);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain this function you wrote a little bit in more details? Right now what I have in service ctor: $http.get("..").success(function(data){ ListService.service.items = data; }); is it different?

Comment: I resolve the value in the getter instead of the constructor and return a promise instead of the resolved object.

Comment: Ah you made it work as lazy initalization? However, why would I need to return a promise? if the request to the server is successful I just want to save the data in an array in the service that made the request without handling it in the controller in any way, just as I mentioned above. The binding will than be direct to the array kept in the service

Comment: Well, using this approach you have the opportunity in your controller where you using the service to do something only if the data is already resolved or for example display a loading pannel until its resolved.

Comment: Good to know, but what I was actually asking was if it was good to actually preserve data in the singleton services. It actually means that each change in the server I will need to make the same change on the data I hold there. Meaning it will force me to have more logic code in client side than just using HTTP GET everytime a controller is created. I guess it's more efficient that way, any other considerations that should be taken?

Comment: I think this is a different question since you can use tools like swagger to generate your client?

Comment: I don't see how swagger relates here.. what I'm simply asking is- in an application without too much data,  such as the one I work on, should I once at start up fetch all data to client and preserve it in a service? By that I could avoid making alot of HTTP GET requests later on. Is it bad practice? If so than why